# How to use DWitemstatus in Power Builder

Tags: oracle, powerbuilder

I'm learning about Power Builder, and i don't know how to use these, (DWitemstatus, getnextmodified, modifiedcount, getitemstatus, NotModified!, DataModified!, New!, NewModified!)
please help me.

Thanks for read !

Answer (score 0):

These relate to the status of rows in a datawindow.  Generally the rows are retrieved from a database but this doesn't always have to be the case - data can be imported from a text file, XML, JSON, etc. as well.

**DWItemstatus** - these values are constants and describe how the data would be changed in the database.
Values are:

1. NotModified! - data unchanged since retrieved
2. DataModified! - data in one or more columns has changed
3. New! - row is new but no values have been assigned
4. NewModifed! - row is new and at least one value has been assigned to a column.

So in terms of SQL, a row which is not modified would not generate any SQL to the DBMS.  A DataModified row would typically generate an UPDATE statement.  New and NewModifed would typically generate INSERT statements.

**GetNextModifed** is a method to search a set of rows in a datawindow to find the modified rows within that set.  The method takes a buffer parameter and a row parameter.  The datawindow buffers are Primary!, Filter!, and Delete!.  In general you would only look at the Primary buffer.

**ModifedCount** is a method to determine the number of rows which have been modifed in a datawindow.  Note that deleting a row is not considered a modification. To find the number of rows deleted use the DeletedCount method.

**GetItemStatus** is a method to get the status of column within a row in a data set in a datawindow.  It takes the parameters row, column (name or number), and DWBuffer.

So now an example of using this:

```
// loop through rows checking for changes
IF dw_dash.Modifiedcount() > 0 THEN
  ll = dw_dash.GetNextModified(0,Primary!)
  ldw = dw_dash
  DO WHILE ll > 0
    // watch value changed
    IF ldw.GetItemStatus(ll,'watch',Primary!) = DataModified! THEN
      event we_post_item(ll, 'watch', ldw)
    END IF
    // followup value changed
    IF ldw.GetItemStatus(ll,'followupdate',Primary!) = DataModified! THEN
      event we_post_item(ll, 'followupdate', ldw)
    END IF
    ll = ldw.GetNextModified(ll,Primary!)
  LOOP
  ldw.resetupdate() //reset the modifed flags
END IF
```

In this example we first check to see if any row in the datawindow has been modified.  Then we get the first modified row and check if either the 'watch' or 'followupdate' columns were changed.  If they were we trigger an event to do something.  We then loop to the next modified row and so on.  Finally we reset the modified flags so the row would now show as not being mofified.